# Invalid Cast Exception when calling SqlDataReader.GetTimeSpan() or .GetDateTime()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have a little problem in my ASP.NET MVC Application.
In my class Repository.cs I call a StoredProcedure wich gives me something like that:

```
###############################################################
| JOB  | STATUS | DATE       | START    | END      | DURATION |
###############################################################
| ABCD | ok     | 05.05.2015 | 10:15:12 | 10:16:00 | 00:00:48 |
. 
.
.
```

My **Repository.cs** class Code looks like that (rdr is an SqlDataReader):

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    var jobNameId = rdr.GetOrdinal("JOB");
    var statusId = rdr.GetOrdinal("STATUS");
    var appointmentId = rdr.GetOrdinal("DATE");
    var startId = rdr.GetOrdinal("START");
    var endId = rdr.GetOrdinal("END");
    var durationId = rdr.GetOrdinal("DURATION");

    result.Add(new Job()
    {
        JobName = rdr.GetString(jobNameId),
        Status = (JobStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(JobStatus), rdr.GetString(statusId)),
        // rdr.GetDateTime() and rdr.GetTimeSpan() is throwing InvalidCastException
        Appointment = rdr.GetDateTime(appointmentId),
        Start = rdr.GetTimeSpan(startId),
        End = rdr.GetTimeSpan(endId),
        Duration = rdr.GetTimeSpan(durationId)
    });
}
```

My **Job.cs** class looks like that:

```
public class Job
{
    public string JobName { get; set; }

    public JobStatus Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime Appointment { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

}
```

The exception is thrown, when my reader (rdr) tryes to call `rdr.GetDateTime(appointmentId)` and also when it calls `rdr.GetTimeSpan(startId|endId|durationId)`

I know I could do it with `Convert.ToDateTime(rdr.GetString(appointmentId))` but I don't want to do it like that because this doesn't make sense to me.

Do you guys have ideas how I can get my DateTime/TimeSpan, without explicit converting it to a DateTime/TimeSpan?

Comment: What is the schema in the database (or stored proc)?

Comment: @JonSkeet The StoreProcedure takes his elements from a View, and this View only has `varchar` values

Comment: _"I know I could do it with Convert.ToDateTime(rdr.GetString(appointmentId)) but I don't want to do it like that because this doesn't make sense to me"_ You either cant do that because they are not `strings` or you can do that, then you should change the type in the database. It doesn't make sense to use `varchar` for `datetime` or `time`. That also fixes the `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Well that's the problem then, I'd say. If the stored procedure is *meant* to be returning date/time values, it should do so...

Comment: @brothers28: if it's a view change the view or don't use it but the orginal tables.

Comment: @JonSkeet so if I would update my View (I actually didn't wrote it) to return DateTime or Time, It would work?

Comment: @TimSchmelter jeah I know it's not a good approach to return varchar for datetime and time, but i didn't worte the original View...

Comment: Yes, I suspect it would - and it would be better for everyone, basically. Always try hard to return data in its "natural" form :)